# Cannot Create ActiveX Component error on CreateObject or GetObject

Tags: vb.net, com

I have a vb.net windows forms application that I created in VS2010 which works fine.  I want to access that application through a plugin that I am writing to another application.  However, when I use:

```
odt = CreateObject("ODTuner.Application")
```

or

```
odt = GetObject(, "ODTuner.Application")
```

I get an error saying "Cannot Create ActiveX Component".  This works fine when accessing commercial applications, but not for my custom application.  At first I thought this meant that my application wasn't registered, so I registered it using regasm, but that did not solve the problem.  I'm sure this is a simple thing and I am just missing something.  I have searched for answers but haven't found a solution - maybe I am not searching for the right thing?  I would appreciate any help, I've been stuck on this for awhile.

Just some additional info:  What I am writing is a plugin for a commercial application (ModelCenter).  I want that plugin to execute my custom application, but I get the "Cannot Create ActiveX Component" error.  If there is another way to make it execute my app, that would be great, but this is the only way I know of.

UPDATE:  Here is more detail on where I'm at:

I added some attributes to the declaration for my class. The code looks like this:

```
<ComVisibleAttribute(True), _
Guid("4D0CF269-DD2F-4D09-93E8-1975FC253C9E"), _
ProgId("ODTuner.Application"), _
ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)> _
Public Class ODTuner 'frm_ODTuner
```

As I understand it, this should make it COM visible with the ProgId "ODTuner.Application".  Then in my plugin, I have:

```
Dim odt
odt = CreateObject("ODTuner.Application")
```

But, I get the error, "Cannot Create ActiveX Component"  I tried the code in a simple Windows Forms application (one button to execute the CreateObject), to see if it had something to do with the plugin or ModelCenter, but I get the same error there.

I have searched and searched, but cannot figure out why this does not work.  Clearly I've missed something.  Appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to use COM?  If both ends are written in .NET, it would be far preferable to just reference it as a .NET library.

Comment: Creating an out-of-process COM server in .NET is not directly supported.